# basis extension intuition

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, change-of-basis

If we have vectors $v_1, v_2, v_3\in \mathbb R^4$ and we want to extend them to a basis of $\mathbb R^4$, why can we take the vectors as rows and then doing rows reductions with Gauß algorithm and then choose the canonical vector $e_k$ where index $k$ is one of the components that can be set as a free variable? I want to find a reasoning for doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the matrix whose rows are $v_1, v_2, v_3$, say, $A$. Then what we are doing in picking the $e_k$ corresponding to a free variable is finding a basis for the null space of $A$ (which suggests that this works in general, not just when we're missing one vector).

The null space of $A$ completes the basis of $\mathbb R^4$ because null space of $A$ is equal to the orthogonal complement of the row space of $A$ (this is some version of the "four subspaces theorem", relating row and/or column spaces to null spaces).